# How to make Controlled-CRY Gates

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I found that how to make CRY Gates.
But I don't know how to make Controlled-CRY Gates.
Please show me a figure.
[image]
Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: Just replace your controlled-not gates with Toffolis!

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the gate decomposition of $CCR_Y$ then it is:

[image]

The picture above was [taken from this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01618.pdf).

The more generalize case is:

[image]

This is from [this textbook](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) on page 182.

Comment: Thanks for helping!