# How to make the gate decomposition of CCCRY

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I [asked](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14577/9858) about decomposition gate of CCRY last week, and the answer was:

[image]

However, I now also want to do this for CCCRY. Please someone tell me.

Comment: Thank you KAJ226, Yitian Wang and Appo.

Answer (score 1):

There is an automatic way to design a gate, utilizing `qiskit`. When drawing the figure of a quantum, you can use the code `circ.decompose().draw()` to show a decomposed circuit.

Code first:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit,QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates import RYGate
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
qr=QuantumRegister(4)
circ=QuantumCircuit(qr)
a=Parameter('a') # You can replace a with theta here
CCCRY=RYGate(a).control(3)
circ.append(CCCRY,qr)
circ.decompose().draw('mpl')
plt.show()
```

And this gives the following decomposition:

[image: CCCRY]

In this figure, $U_3(\theta,\phi,\lambda)=RZ(\phi)RX(-\pi/2)RZ(\theta)RX(\pi/2)RZ(\lambda)$, so $U_3(\theta,0,0)=RY(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can design $n$-controlled $U$ gate, $CCC\cdots CU = C^{n}U $, using the technique from [Mike and Ike](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) on page 184, starting with

[image]

where

[image]

and here your $Controlled-U$ is $CR_y$ which is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same trick by replacing $RY(\theta)$ by $CRY(\theta)$ i.e

$$ CCCRY = CC(CRY) $$

Then you can continue the simplification process till you find an excutable circuit.